# Where is the initial git configuration saved?

Tags: git

During installation, we checked “Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style” instead of “Checkout as-is, commit as-is”
On windows.

It is not updated in the global config.

Please check the below output once.

```
$ git config --list | grep crlf

core.autocrlf=true
```

No output for below commands, means not configured in those files.

```
git config --list --global | grep crlf

git config --list --system | grep crlf
```

Please suggest where it got updated.

`--local` also no output.

Answer (score 0):

You can see where a particular git configuration value is set using the [`--show-origin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---show-origin) option:

```
git config --list --show-origin | grep crlf
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. The file is in
On the machine where git installed.: “c:\programdata\git\config”
On the machine where only GitHub desktop installed: “%localappdata%\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.6\resources\app\git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig”